# Can I get AMI details with out creating the EC2 instance from AMI in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to get AMI details like Operating System Type, Operating System Version and Softwares that were used to build the AMI without creating EC2 instance of it.

I know that I can get the details by creating a EC2 Instance from the AMI.

I what to get these details without creating EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes you can...https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes.  It all depends on who created the AMI.  In general, an [AMI provides the following information](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_images):

```
'Architecture': 'i386'|'x86_64'|'arm64',
'CreationDate': 'string',
'ImageId': 'string',
'ImageLocation': 'string',
'ImageType': 'machine'|'kernel'|'ramdisk',
'Public': True|False,
'KernelId': 'string',
'OwnerId': 'string',
'Platform': 'Windows',
'ProductCodes': [
    {
        'ProductCodeId': 'string',
        'ProductCodeType': 'devpay'|'marketplace'
    },
],
'RamdiskId': 'string',
'State': 'pending'|'available'|'invalid'|'deregistered'|'transient'|'failed'|'error',
'BlockDeviceMappings': [
    {
        'DeviceName': 'string',
        'VirtualName': 'string',
        'Ebs': {
            'DeleteOnTermination': True|False,
            'Iops': 123,
            'SnapshotId': 'string',
            'VolumeSize': 123,
            'VolumeType': 'standard'|'io1'|'gp2'|'sc1'|'st1',
            'Encrypted': True|False,
            'KmsKeyId': 'string'
        },
        'NoDevice': 'string'
    },
],
'Description': 'string',
'EnaSupport': True|False,
'Hypervisor': 'ovm'|'xen',
'ImageOwnerAlias': 'string',
'Name': 'string',
'RootDeviceName': 'string',
'RootDeviceType': 'ebs'|'instance-store',
'SriovNetSupport': 'string',
'StateReason': {
    'Code': 'string',
    'Message': 'string'
},
'Tags': [
    {
        'Key': 'string',
        'Value': 'string'
    },
],
'VirtualizationType': 'hvm'|'paravirtual'
```

So while you can get the architecture, unless the creator included a `Name`, `Desription`, or `Tags` with the information you are looking for, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can query AMI using CLI, Console and APIs.

An example CLI to query AMI using ami-id is as below:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --region us-east-1 --image-ids ami-XXXXXXXXXX
```